# .Net DataGridView Vertical Scrollbar Error with Multiline Rows

Tags: datagridview, scrollbar

I have an unbound DataGridView. I have the ScrollBars property set to Both.  The columns are textboxes, with WrapMode set to true, to allow for multiple lines per row.  If I have several rows that expand beyond the height of the dgv, the vertical scrollbar appears, and functions properly.

On rare occasions, I will have a single row that has so many lines, it will grow taller than the dgv itself.  When this happens, the scrollbar does not appear at all.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HNElt.jpg

Column3 should be:

A,A
B,B
C,C
D,D
E,E
F,F

Has anyone seen this before? Any suggestions?

Comment: I have experienced that before. It seems to be the normal behavior.